# Why is negative char number converting differently?

Tags: c++

I need to convert characters from a string into int's then place them into a vector. I started by making a new string of the numbers without the spaces. I then want to iterate through the numbers in the result string and convert to int, then push into a vector. I am having issues with the negative numbers not converting to the right values. I commented out the vector part because I realized the issue is before that, the wrong values are going into the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

string result = "";
string str = "8 3 -5 42 -1 0 0 -9 4 7 4 -4";

for(char c : str) {
    if(c == ' ') {
        continue;
    }
    else {
        result += c;
    }
}

cout << "result: " << result;

vector<int> lst;
//for(int x = 0; x < result.length(); x++) {
    //lst.push_back(result[x] - '0');
//}
 //testing the values being converted
 int x = result[2] - '0';
cout << "\n" << x;
```

}

For example,

```
int x = result[0] - '0';
cout << "\n" << x;
```

gives me 8, which is the right conversion of the first number in the string.

but,

```
int x = result[2] - '0';
cout << "\n" << x;
```

gives me -3, which is not the -5 I am looking for. I am stuck on this and I cannot figure out why the negative numbers are not properly converting, or where the -3 is even coming from. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `std::stringstream strm(str); std::vector<int> lst; int val; while (strm >> val) lst.push_back(val);`.  That does what you are attempting to do.

Comment: `'0' == 48`, `'-' == 45`, `45 - 48 == -3`, it's perfectly logical. I'm now sure why you expected -5, can you explain the rationale? You'd get -5 if the input were `'+'` and not `'-'` because `'+' == 43` and `43 - 48 == -5`.

Comment: I see, I thought that the "-5" would be read as a single unit, but it is reading the negative value by itself, separate from the 5. I think?

Comment: *I thought that the "-5" would be read as a single unit,* -- Leave that job to `std::stringstream` -- there is no need to check for spaces, negative signs, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes that seems to be the best solution here, I just have no idea how the stringstream syntax works so I am gonna have to look this up to understand the implementation. Thanks.

Comment: @user15442068 A `stringstream` is just as if you entered those values from the keyboard or an input file.  The only difference is that the input is in a string.  That's why you see the `>>` being used, exactly the same way as if you did `cin >> val`

Answer (score 2):

Your input is: "8 3 -5 42 -1 0 0 -9 4 7 4 -4"

You put non-space characters into the result array, so:
result[0]->'8'
result[1]->'3'
result[2]->'-'
result[3]->'5'

So `result[2]` is `-` which has an ASCII code of 45. The zero digit has an ASCII code of 48. So `result[2] - '0'` is 45 minus 48 or -3.

You don't say why you expect -5. What character do you think is five less than the digit zero?

Comment: Yes I see why this is happening now, I thought that the -5 would be read as a single unit, or character. The '-' is being read by itself, which is what I now realize.

Comment: I am trying to get the -5 to be turned into -5 as an int.